# Barebones Qt/QML app that generates a list of dishes and then a shopping list with ingredients

Tags: c++, object-oriented, database, qt, qml

I have written a simple app that generates a menu in the form of a list of recipes.
It furthermore generates a shopping list, given a menu, consisting of the (unique) ingredients in the recipes that make up the menu.

A database provides a list of all possible recipes and the related ingredients. Here is its structure:

`recipe` table:

| id (P) | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Beef stew |
| ... | ... |

`ingredient` table:

| id (P) | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Beef |
| 2 | Red wine |
| ... | ... |

`recipeIngredient` table:

| recipe_id (F) | ingredient_id (F) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| ... | ... |

The app opens and interacts with the database in a C++ class, and shows the user the menu/list with QML code.
I am fairly new to both QML and databases. looking for general feedback on the design of this software, feel free to be as critical as you feel necessary.
I also have some detailed questions:

- I am using a simple SQLite3 database for my application. From a bit of research I have done, I understand the Qt resource system cannot handle database files directly (see for example [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/14714/adding-db-to-resources)), as  that would pass the qrc URI to the SQlite driver, which would then be unable to locate the file. Furthermore, resource files are read-only. What is then the best practice for shipping a database with an application? Is packaging the database with the app and installing it to a known location together with the app the way to go? I would do that by configuring the CMake installer in `CMakeLists.txt` with something like `install(FILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/res/recipes.db" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR})`, and then try to locate that and open it from `DBManager.cpp`. But I suppose this is not possible when cross-compiling for another platform, e.g. when packaging an apk for android. Another strategy I encountered for solving this problem is to declare the database file as a resource and then copying it to an accessible location at runtime (see `main.cpp`), using `QStandardPaths`. My understanding is that the database would then exist, at any given time, both in the apk as a resource file and somewhere else on the target system, which seems like a waste of space and could potentially make the apk very large if the database is extended.
- Am I accessing the database in a sensible way? Supposing this will scale to a large database with many recipes, should I be concerned with some specific metric when I design my queries (e.g. minimizing the number of queries)?
- It seems to me there is some repetition of code in the QML files, am I not using some patterns that I should instead employ?
- Is my way of controlling QML elements with buttons sensible or am I missing some easier way of making the buttons affect what goes on on the screen?

main.cpp:

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QStandardPaths>

#include "DBManager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Supposing I copy the file at runtime
    QFile::copy(":/databases/ricettario.db", QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation) + "/ricettario.db");

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/MenuHelper/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(
        &engine,
        &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app,
        []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);

    DBManager* recipeDBManager = new DBManager();
    qmlRegisterSingletonInstance("MenuHelper", 1, 0, "DBManager", recipeDBManager);

    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

DBManager.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtQml/qqmlregistration.h>

class DBManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    QML_SINGLETON

public:
    explicit DBManager(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~DBManager();

    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList menuRecipes  READ menuRecipes    NOTIFY menuRecipesChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList shoppingList READ shoppingList   NOTIFY shoppingListChanged)

    Q_INVOKABLE void generateMenu();
    Q_INVOKABLE void generateShoppingList();
    Q_INVOKABLE void swapRecipe(int index);
    Q_INVOKABLE void deleteRecipe(int index);
    Q_INVOKABLE void addRecipe();
    Q_INVOKABLE void deleteIngredient(int index);

    QStringList menuRecipes() const { return _menuRecipes; }
    QStringList shoppingList() const { return _shoppingList; }


signals:
    void menuRecipesChanged();
    void shoppingListChanged();

private:
    QString _findNewRecipe() const;

    QSqlDatabase _recipeDatabaseConnection;
    QStringList _menuRecipes, _shoppingList;
};
```

DBManager.cpp:

```
#include "DBManager.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QStandardPaths>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

DBManager::DBManager(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
    , _recipeDatabaseConnection(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"))
{
    _recipeDatabaseConnection.setDatabaseName(QStandardPaths::locate(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation, "ricettario.db"));
    if(!_recipeDatabaseConnection.open()){
        qWarning() << _recipeDatabaseConnection.lastError().text();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Succesfully opened" << _recipeDatabaseConnection.databaseName() << "for reading";
    }
}

DBManager::~DBManager()
{
    _recipeDatabaseConnection.close();
}

void DBManager::generateMenu()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("SELECT name FROM recipe ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3");
    _menuRecipes.clear();
    while(query.next()){
        _menuRecipes.append(query.value(0).toString());
    }
    emit menuRecipesChanged();
}

void DBManager::swapRecipe(int index)
{
    QString newRecipe = _findNewRecipe();
    if (!newRecipe.isEmpty()){
        _menuRecipes[index] = newRecipe;
        emit menuRecipesChanged();
    }
}

void DBManager::deleteRecipe(int index)
{
    _menuRecipes.removeAt(index);
    emit menuRecipesChanged();
}

void DBManager::addRecipe()
{
    QString newRecipe = _findNewRecipe();
    if (!newRecipe.isEmpty()){
        _menuRecipes.append(newRecipe);
        emit menuRecipesChanged();
    }
}

void DBManager::deleteIngredient(int index)
{
    _shoppingList.removeAt(index);
    emit shoppingListChanged();
}

QString DBManager::_findNewRecipe() const
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("SELECT name FROM recipe "
               "WHERE name NOT IN (\"" + _menuRecipes.join("\", \"") + "\") "
                                               "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 ");
    if(query.next()){
        return query.value(0).toString();
    } else {
        qWarning() << "Could not find another recipe";
        return QString();
    }
}

void DBManager::generateShoppingList()
{
    _shoppingList.clear();
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("SELECT DISTINCT ingredient.name FROM recipe "
               "JOIN recipe_ingredient ON recipe.id = recipe_ingredient.recipe_id "
               "JOIN ingredient ON recipe_ingredient.ingredient_id = ingredient.id "
               "WHERE recipe.name IN (\"" + _menuRecipes.join("\", \"") + "\")");
    while(query.next()){
        _shoppingList.append(query.value(0).toString());
    }
    emit shoppingListChanged();
}
```

main.qml:

```javascript
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import MenuHelper

Window {
    width: 400
    height: 800
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Menu Helper")

    color: MyPalette.secondaryColor

    TopBanner{
        id:             topBanner
        titleText:      qsTr("Menu")
        anchors.top:    parent.top
        anchors.left:   parent.left
        anchors.right:  parent.right
        height:         ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 8
    }

    MenuListArea{
        id:             recipesList
        anchors.top:    topBanner.bottom
        anchors.left:   parent.left
        anchors.right:  parent.right
        anchors.bottom: buttonsBar.top
    }

    ShoppingListArea{
        id:             shoppingList
        anchors.top:    topBanner.bottom
        anchors.left:   parent.left
        anchors.right:  parent.right
        anchors.bottom: buttonsBar.top
        visible:        !recipesList.visible
    }

    Rectangle {
        id:                 buttonsBar
        anchors.left:       parent.left
        anchors.right:      parent.right
        anchors.bottom:     parent.bottom
        height:             ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 10
        color:          MyPalette.tertiaryColor

        RowLayout{
            anchors.centerIn:   parent
            spacing:            ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2

            Button {
                id:         refreshButton
                text:       recipesList.visible ? qsTr("Generate new menu") : qsTr("Back to menu")
                onClicked:  {
                    if (recipesList.visible){
                        DBManager.generateMenu()
                    } else {
                        recipesList.visible = true
                        topBanner.titleText = qsTr("Menu")
                    }
                }
            }

            Button {
                id:         shoppingListButton
                text:       qsTr("To list")
                onClicked:  {
                    DBManager.generateShoppingList()
                    recipesList.visible = false
                    topBanner.titleText = qsTr("Shopping List")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MenuListArea.qml:

```javascript
import QtQuick 6.4
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import MenuHelper

Rectangle {
    id:                 _root
    anchors.margins:    ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2

    Component {
        id:             recipeComponent

        RowLayout {
            width:      _root.width

            Text {
                Layout.alignment:   Qt.AlignLeft
                Layout.fillWidth:   true
                text:               modelData
                wrapMode:           Text.WordWrap
            }

            RowLayout {
                Layout.alignment:   Qt.AlignRight

                Button {
                    icon.source:        "qrc:/icons/swap.svg"
                    icon.color:         MyPalette.secondaryColor
                    icon.width:         ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2
                    icon.height:        ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2
                    implicitWidth:      icon.width + padding * 2
                    onClicked:          DBManager.swapRecipe(index)
                }

                Button {
                    icon.source:        "qrc:/icons/delete.svg"
                    icon.color:         MyPalette.secondaryColor
                    icon.width:         ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2
                    icon.height:        ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2
                    implicitWidth:      icon.width + padding * 2
                    onClicked:          DBManager.deleteRecipe(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id:             recipeList
        model:          DBManager.menuRecipes
        delegate:       recipeComponent
        height:         contentHeight
    }

    Button {
        anchors.right:      parent.right
        anchors.top:        recipeList.bottom
        icon.source:        "qrc:/icons/add.svg"
        icon.color:         MyPalette.secondaryColor
        icon.width:         ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2
        icon.height:        ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2
        implicitWidth:      icon.width + padding * 2
        onClicked:          DBManager.addRecipe()
    }
}
```

ShoppingListArea.qml:

```javascript
import QtQuick 6.4
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import MenuHelper

Rectangle {
    id:                 _root
    anchors.margins:    ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2

    Component {
        id:             recipeComponent
        RowLayout {
            width:      _root.width

            Text {
                Layout.alignment:   Qt.AlignLeft
                text:               modelData
            }

            Button {
                Layout.alignment:   Qt.AlignRight
                icon.source:        "qrc:/icons/delete.svg"
                icon.color:         MyPalette.secondaryColor
                icon.width:         ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2
                icon.height:        ScreenSizes.defaultFontPixelHeight * 2
                implicitWidth:      icon.width + padding * 2
                onClicked:          DBManager.deleteIngredient(index)
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id:             recipeList
        model:          DBManager.shoppingList
        delegate:       recipeComponent
        anchors.fill:   parent
    }
}
```

TopBanner.qml:

```javascript
import QtQuick 6.4

Item {
    property string titleText
    Rectangle {
        id:                 background
        anchors.fill:       parent
        color:              MyPalette.primaryColor
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn:   background
        text:               titleText
        color:              MyPalette.secondaryColor
        font.pointSize:     ScreenSizes.extraLargeFontPointSize
    }
}
```